# Proof of alternating conditional expectation base equations

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, bayes, conditional-expectation

How do we prove the base equations for Alternating Conditional Expectation algorithm. The statement is thus:
We define arbitrary mean-zero transformation $\theta(Y),\phi(X_i)$,$1<i<p$ for dependent variable $Y$ and independent variable $X$. A regression of the transformed independent variable case on the sum of transformed independent variables, (in this case we have just one variable)   yields an error $e^2(\theta,\phi)=E([\theta(X)-\phi(Y)]^2)$. PROVE THAT ON Minimizing this w.r.t $\phi(X)$, under the constraint $E[\theta(Y)^2]=1$,  **${\phi(x)=E[\theta(Y)|X]}$** and on minimizing w.r.t $\theta(Y)$, **$\theta(Y)=\frac{E[\phi(X)|Y]}{||E[\phi(X)|Y]||}$.**

ThankYou!

Comment: Is this a question for a course? (-- the instruction "PROVE THAT" suggests it)  $\quad$ If I am remembering correctly, an outline proof is in the original ACE paper; it may be worth reading for some ideas.